# Why doesnt javascript check object's local scope first?

Tags: javascript

Why doesnt the outer scope get accessed in the inner scope ?

I am coming from C++ world where any reference to an unqualified variable inside a class's method is attempted to be resolved first within the object's scope and then in the outer scope. And this happens without having to use "this" keyword.
For ex:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::string name = "Global::name";

class MyClass {
    private:
        string name = "MyClass::name";
    public:
        void printName() {
            // No need to use 'this' keyword to refer to the variables in the
            // object's scope, unless there is an ambiguity to resolve
            cout << "Name from inside printName is: " << name << "\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    cout << "Name from inside main is: " << name << "\n";
    obj.printName();
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
Name from inside main is: Global::name                                                                 
Name from inside printName is: MyClass::name
```

But in javascript, the following code snippet

```
function fn() {
    let name1 = "fnB";
    console.log("Inside fn() name is : ", name1);
}


var obj = {
    name1: "objA",
    objFn: function() {
        console.log("Inside objFn() name is : ", name1); // ERROR !!
        // console.log("Inside objFn() name is : ", this.name1); // OK !
    }
}

fn();
obj.objFn();
```

results in

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: name1 is not defined
    at Object.objFn (my.js:10)
```

What is the reason javascript doesnt want to refer to the "name1" variable in the scope of "obj" object, without requiring "this" keyword to refer to it ? What is the problem that is being solved by forcing the use of "this" keyword in this context ?

Comment: because that is how it works?

Comment: Objects do not create "scope" in JavaScript. Also there is no strong relationship between functions and the objects they are assigned to as properties. Consider the following in your example: `var f = obj.objFn; f();` What should `name1` refer to then? What you are expecting seems to work in languages where functions are not standalone objects, or there is a difference between functions and object methods, but that's not the case in JavaScript.

Comment: Why do you make the assumption that objects in JavaScript should work like classes/objects in C++? They are not the same

Comment: properties are different from variables. properties are attached to the objects but variables defined inside the scope of functions.

Comment: I recommend to read these articles: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-4-scope-chain/. http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-1-lexical-environments-common-theory/. http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-2-lexical-environments-ecmascript-implementation/, https://codeburst.io/js-scope-static-dynamic-and-runtime-augmented-5abfee6223fe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every language is different and makes different tradeoffs. An obvious difference between C++ and JavaScript wrt class/object methods:

- In JavaScript, every function is a standalone object. It doesn't strongly belong to anything.

  - In C++, class methods belongs the class. They cannot be invoked without it.
- In JavaScript, every function is a closure, i.e. it has access to free variables defined in a "higher" lexical scope.

  - In C++, methods are not closures.

Why does this matter? Consider the following example:

```
var name = 42;

var obj = {
    name: "objA",
    objFn: function() {
        console.log("Inside objFn() name is : ", name);
    }
}
```

Which `name` should `objFn` access according to your expectation?

As it is now, the function would log `42`, because that's how lexical scoping + closures work. In order to access the object's `name` property I have to write `this.name`.

Now lets assume it was the other way round, that object properties would be accessed before the outer scope. Then in order to explicitly access the outer scope's variables, i.e. `42`, we would need some new API, e.g. `getVariableFromScope('name')`. This is worse than always requiring `this` for a simple reason: It makes it more difficult to reason about the code. By always requiring `this`, the rules are very simply:

- Want to access a property on the object? `this.<property>`
- Want to access a variable in scope? `<variable>`

In your case it would be:

- Want to access a variable in scope? `<variable>`, but only if the object doesn't have a property with the same name, otherwise `getVariableFromScope('<variable>')`.
- Want to access a property on the object? `<property>`, but only if there is not a *local* variable with the same name, otherwise `this.<property>`.

One possible tradeoff here is consistency vs convenience.

Also consider the following example:

```
var foo = 42;
function bar() {
  console.log(foo);
}
```

Calling `bar()` will log `42`. Now lets assume I pass the function to some third-party code `someOtherFunction(foo)` which does:

```
function someOtherFunction(func) {
  var obj = createObject();
  obj.func = func;
  obj.func();
}
```

Do you see the problem? The result of calling `bar` now depends on whether `obj` has a `name` property or not. To resolve this, either `someOtherFunction` needs to know which free variables `bar` contains or `bar` needs to know that `someOtherFunction` assigns it to some object and has to account for that. Either way, the code would be tightly coupled.

Doing what C++ or Java does would basically mean to introduce [*dynamic scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping), and I assume there is a reason why very few languages use it.

(Someone might argue that `this` is also like dynamic scope. Well, `this` is a single keyword. It's easier to reason about that than to reason about the space of all possible variable names that could be overwritten.)

---

There are probably more reason why the behavior you are describing is not desirable in JavaScript. But again, programming language design is all about tradeoffs.

Comment: > "Now lets assume it was the other way round, that object properties would be accessed before the outer scope. Then in order to explicitly access the outer scope's variables, i.e. 42, we would need some new API, e.g. getVariableFromScope('name'). "

C++'s answer to this would be the "::" operator

`int x = 5;
   int main()
   {
       int x = 1;
       cout << "The variable x: " << ::x << endl;  // prints "5"
   }`

Comment: I guess C++ functions  / methods can be considered closures then ? Either way, this kind of supports my point about tradeoffs: C++ has a separate operator for that, whereas that's not necessary in JavaScript, with the tradeoff that you always have to qualify accessing object properties. Btw, what I'm talking about is mostly syntax, there might also be implementation related reasons why bringing the object into the function's scope is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword behaves quite differently in javascript from how it does in many other languages. The value of `this` is not figured out until the function is invoked, and may not have anything to do with the object you think its associated with.

For example, consider the following code:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'bob',
  sayName: function () {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

const verbalize = obj.sayName; // Make another way to reference the function

console.log(verbalize === obj.sayName); // They're literally the same function

// And yet they log very different things
obj.sayName();  // logs 'bob'
verbalize();  // for me, it logs 1d7dcb5e-0fde-4726-8875-4bdcd636c6eb
```

Why does verbalize produce such a weird result? Well, since i'm invoking the function without specifying what `this` should be equal to, `this` defaults to the global `window` object, and so i end up logging `window.name`, which for me happens to be "1d7dcb5e-0fde-4726-8875-4bdcd636c6eb".

So if the language was set up to check `this` before checking other scopes, the actual result would be (in some cases) to check for global variables before local variables, which is the exact *opposite* of what we'd like to happen. Thus, `this` has to be done explicitly.

(ps: while `this` can be set to the window object in some cases, it can also be set to `undefined` if you're in strict mode)